# Cant seem to use/find ListDictionary

Tags: c#, xaml

Im creating a XAML/WPF/C# program and am trying to store some objects in a listdictionary, but the IDE isnt recognising ListDictionary<>.
I am using the namespace System.Collections.Specialized which is where MSDN states it is found. 
Any idea why this might be?

Comment: That type (and the whole namespace really) is effectively obsolete as of .NET 2.0.  Use `LinkedList<T>` if you need a linked list (although I can't imagine why you'd want to use a linked list for something like this either).  You probably should just use `Dictionary<>`

Comment: What im trying to do is add a whole bunch of objects (which contains a bunch of text fields) to the dictionary, then search it for a particular phrase at a particular time.  Is Dictionary<> the best thing to use here then? Incidentally, the reason im trying to use ListDictionary is based on a tutorial from MS Virtual Academy, which i believe is based on .net 4.5.  Can supply the link if necessary

Comment: Sounds like you should run away from that tutorial then, it sounds like it's trying to encourage you to use extremely outdated types that weren't even appropriate for the situation at hand 13 years ago when they were actually  not *entirely* obsolete.  Whether you want a `Dictionary` or not is going to depend on the specifics of what you're doing, but whatever you want is almost certainly going to be in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, not `Specialized`.

Comment: heres the tute if you want to judge for yourself: http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners?m=7675

Comment: then you want class 22 - working with collections

Comment: Working with collections is section 22...

Comment: Right you are.  Updated

Comment: Either way - he is definitely using ListDictionary in 4.5 so im not sure why im not seeing it at all.  Based on his example, it would make it SUPER simple to search all my objects for a particular string attached to one of the properties in each object

Comment: ignore that - keep watching and he changes it all to a list...d'oh

Comment: According to the section description he uses dated collections specifically to compare them to more modern versions to contrast how useful some of the features of the modern collections are.  Hopefully he's not actually advocating use of those dated collections; did the actual course itself give you the impression that you should be using them?  Personally I don't see that as being a productive approach.

Comment: Your right servy - i was getting ahead of myself.  He shows how using List and Dictionary is actually better.  I learnt something today :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic version of ListDictionary. It's always an (object,object) pair.